# Inner forEach in forEach jstl error

Tags: java, jstl

I faced with such problem. I write such jstl code:

```
<c:forEach var="package" items="${hotel.packages}">
    <c:forEach var="product_item" items="${package.items}">
           //some inputs and so on    
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

my model class look like this:

**Hotel class**

```
private java.util.Set<com.acmecorp.acmeproject.model.catalog.hotel.HotelPackage> packages;
public java.util.Set<com.acmecorp.acmeproject.model.catalog.hotel.HotelPackage> getPackages() { /* compiled code */ }

public void setPackages(java.util.Set<com.acmecorp.acmeproject.model.catalog.hotel.HotelPackage> packages) { /* compiled code */ }
```

**HotelPackage**

```
    public java.util.Set<com.acmecorp.acmeproject.model.catalog.hotel.HotelPackageItem> getItems() { /* compiled code */ }

    public void setItems(java.util.Set<com.acmecorp.acmeproject.model.catalog.hotel.HotelPackageItem> items) { /* compiled code */ }
private java.util.Set<com.acmecorp.acmeproject.model.catalog.hotel.HotelPackageItem> items;
```

I'm geting this message

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/view/controls/hotelPackages/hotelPackagesView.jsp (line: 165, column: 24) "${package.items}" contains invalid expression(s): javax.el.ELException: Failed to parse the expression [${package.items}]
```

while trying to open my jsp.
line 164 it is this line `<c:forEach var="product_item" items="${package.items}">`

So, may be someone know what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is because 'package' is a reserved Java keyword. Try renaming it to basically anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer!

### your class Hotel

```
public class Hotel {
public java.util.HashSet<HotelPackage> packages;

public java.util.HashSet<HotelPackage> getPackages() {
    return packages;
}

public void setPackages(java.util.HashSet<HotelPackage> packages) {
    this.packages = packages;
}

}
```

### your class

```
public class HotelPackage {
public java.util.HashSet<String> items;

public java.util.HashSet<String> getItems() {
    return items;
}

public void setItems(java.util.HashSet<String> items) {
    this.items = items;
}


}
```

### your jstl code

```
<%
HashSet items = new HashSet();
Hotel hotel = new Hotel();


HashSet hotelPackSet = new HashSet();
HotelPackage hp1 = new HotelPackage();
HashSet items1 = new HashSet();
items1.add("Buffet");
items1.add("Luxury Rooms");
hotelPackSet.add(hp1);

HotelPackage hp2 = new HotelPackage();
HashSet items2 = new HashSet();
hp2.setItems(items2);

items2.add("Swimming Pool");
items2.add("Common Rooms");

hotelPackSet.add(hp1);
hotelPackSet.add(hp2);

hotel.setPackages(hotelPackSet);
%>
<c:set property="hotel" scope="page" value="<%= hotel%>" var="hotel"/>
<c:forEach var="pack" items="${hotel.packages}">
<c:set property="packItem" scope="page" value="${pack.items}" var="pack"/>
    <c:forEach var="product_item" items="${pack}">
           ${product_item}   
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

---

So you are doing a big mistake by not setting up var in set variable.Cheers :)

Comment: Also,you were using package which is a keyword.In addition you were trying to access private fields directly

Comment: ugh, public class properties. WRONG.